# Why would I want to use a laser scope?

Tags: max-payne-3

Some of the weapons in Max Payne 3 have a laser scope attached to them. While this is pretty cool, I actually find it more difficult to aim with these guns as the laser scope disables my targeting reticule, making it more difficult to figure out what I'm going to hit when I shoot (the beam points where Max is pointing the gun, which most time isn't where my shots end up when firing).

Are there any advantages to the laser sight that I am overlooking? Currently I just turn it off if I happen to pick up a weapon that has one.

Comment: I've seen this in several games and usually find it distracting rather than useful.

Answer (score 1):

You will know exactly where your bullets will go. When going into last stand, your weapon does not follow your crosshair immediately while turning around.

Other than that, the bullets follow the crosshair pretty closely, so you can safely turn the laser sight off if you wish. It's probably a feature they intended to flesh out some more, but never did.